# Code for creating Native Window in Qt does not Work: Windows does not show up

Tags: windows, qt

I've been trying to mix a Qt QML Windows application that will open a Native Windows Window in order to Draw on it, using DirectX.

I'm stuck just trying to open the Window.

Here is the code:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "control.h"

// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Control control(nullptr);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("control",&control);

    engine.load(url);

    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)::GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    STARTUPINFO startupinfo;
    GetStartupInfo(&startupinfo);
    int nCmdShow = startupinfo.wShowWindow;
    qDebug() << "HINSTANCE" << hInstance << "nCmdShow" << nCmdShow;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = {0, 0, 800, 600};
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    HWND hWnd;
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          L"WindowClass",
                          L"Our First Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          300,
                          300,
                          wr.right - wr.left,
                          wr.bottom - wr.top,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);


    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    return app.exec();
}
```

As I undestand it this, should open the QML Window (which it does) and another black window that was created using the Window API.

However only the QML window opens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unsure why you do that but you could have draw something in QML, say, with Canvas: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html. Or there many other ways to draw depending on the effort.

Comment: you  add User32.lib and User32.dll?

Comment: @vah: Failure to link against the import library will issue a linker error. Not sure how you'd *"add User32.dll"*. This is a system module.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexa#requirements

Comment: Answering to the comments. I need to do this in order to draw with DX11. This will eventually be drawn in a hardware that requires this. So none of the normal Qt drawing methods will work. As the HW comes with its own API. What I want to do is draw what I need using the DX11 and then I can do a straight port when the HW arrives (I don't have it yet). Second, yes I need to add User32 and Kernel32 libs in order to compile and link. If I copy and paste the code as is, remove all main and QML references and just compile the code, with a WinMain, it works.

Comment: Have you tried passing `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` to `ShowWindow` instead of obtaining `nCmdShow` from `GetStartupInfo`?

Comment: No I haven't. I'm very new at this and have no experience using the Windows API. I will try to use it when I get to work. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll report back

Comment: @aarelovich, As far as I can see, `wShowWindow ` obtained from `GetStartupInfo` is not equivalent to `nCmdShow` from `WinMain`. If I am not mistaken, this has to do with the flag `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` in the member `dwFlags`. Consider [this snippet](https://pastebin.com/99YirHqQ) for an example.

Comment: @Mike It could be. I got the idea to use GetStartupInfo from another question SO. But now that I think about it, I might have used GetStartupInfo, wrong and the 0 value that I get, is incorrect. Makes sense

Comment: OpenGL does draw on hardware via DirectX on Windows if the system is so poor that it better be using DirectX or Qt just configured and built like that. In fact most of my Windows Qt app ports use ANGLE and in turn with DirectX: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5_on_Windows_ANGLE_and_OpenGL https://wiki.qt.io/QtQuick2-and-OpenGL-vs-DirectX-vs-Mesa

Comment: Look for OpenGL Options for Windows: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html

Comment: OpenGL is not an option as the hardware only supportes DX11.

Comment: @Mike, your answer was correct!! Doing what you've said WORKED! Thank you! Post it as answer so I may mark it as correct!

Comment: glad to hear that! Unfortunately, I couldn't find the exact details about the difference between `nCmdShow` and the member `wShowWindow` in `STARTUPINFO` in the documentation. Maybe someone more knowledgeable here can provide more information about the difference (e.g. by examining the code snippet I posted in my previous comment). Good luck!